# Enabling several options for local delivery Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce for Wordpress and I was wondering if there were a way to enable several local delivery options.
I want to apply different fees according to the state (ie: New York 5.99$ and Alaska 10.99$).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce has a "Local Pickup Plus" premium plugin ($$) which handles multiple pickup locations as well as multiple prices.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/local-pickup-plus/